# Sign into WPA2 network that requires a username from mac terminal?

Tags: wireless-networking, terminal.app, wpa2

I am trying to sign into my school's network through terminal. It has WPA2 security, however it requires that I put a username along with a password. Is this possible to do from terminal?

Side note: When not using terminal, once you try to connect to the network it will just prompt the user for a username and password.

--Also, when looking at the network setup help menu (networksetup -h) there is no option that resembles what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Could you clarify what is prompting your username/password - an OS X popup (system window) or Safari (often showing your school's logo/wireless information)? The answers given depend on what you mean by "it will just prompt the user for a username and password"...

Answer (score 1):

I wish networksetup had a username option

> ```
>    networksetup en0 on
>    networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 ssidHERE PSKpasswordHERE
> ```

per airport command in /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources, it doesn't have a username flag ("airport -h" no help either):

> ```
>    airport --password=PSKpasswordHERE --ssid=ssidHERE
> ```

SO, you could create an xml file (note GUI "Apple Configurator 2" app and new profile and configure wi-fi) with pico or something, and NOTE that I've way over-simplied what might be needed inside--not worth the effort compared to GUI join; but you now have the clues if you want to persue:

> ```
>    <key>UserName</key>
>    <string>yourUsernameHERE</string>
>    <key>UserPassword</key>
>    <string>yourPasswordHERE</string>
>    <key>SSID_STR</key>
>    <string>yourSsidHERE</string>
> ```

then run (note if sudo or as root, it will install for all users!):

> ```
>    profiles -I yourxmlfileHERE
> ```

Answer (score -2):

First, WPA2 does not, cannot, require a username.

You very likely have two layers involved:

Wifi, which may be open, and may be WPA/WPA2 with a passphrase.

Captive portal - AFTER you've connected to wifi, if you browse to anywhere, and everything works, you should be redirected to a captive portal web page, which is likely what is asking for the username and password.

Try it graphically first with Safari, if only to validate the redirect and record the actual target location.

Then, if you want to try a terminal app, Lynx is a famous text browser - there's [Lynxlet](https://habilis.net/lynxlet/) for Mac, which might or might not work for you.

Comment: Although the OPs question text doesn't specifically say whether EAP is used, it could also be assumed that because he's asked for a username/password that the school may be using WPA2 Enterprise where, say, they may be using a RADIUS server to authenticate users, which *does* have the ability to accept a username/password/hostname from the client. A captive portal is very feasible so I must give you credit (the lack of detail from the OP doesn't help). Although, due to the traction of RADIUS popularity, this sounds more like what's in place.

Comment: Mac has a command line application "airport" that may be used to configure wireless settings through Terminal - I'm not a Mac user but this may help the OP.

Comment: @Bigchris Agreed, it could be EAP, though "once you try to connect to the network it will just prompt the user for a username and password" sounds more like a captive portal to me, and "my school's" sounds like the OP is a student, and thus less likely to need to get onto an EAP network than a professor or other staff member.

Comment: I work for a University and we use RADIUS (eduroam) and that's WPA2 Enterprise and all our students connect to it using their unique username/password. Staff can use it, too. I've also created a WPA2 Enterprise/RADIUS network for a client and that, too, uses user authentication to connect... It's not difficult to do and RADIUS is becoming an almost defacto method of business wireless nowadays...

Comment: @Bigchris Your university handles security better than many, then, which is great!